# Graficar top 5 por grupo en R

Tags: r

Tengo un dataframe de los jugadores de fútbol de la Liga Santander y me gustaría poder graficar el top 5 por cada club, por lo que me quedarían 20 subgráficas.

```
Jugadores_final %>% 
     group_by(Club) %>% 
          top_n(5, Puntos_totales) %>% 
               ggplot(aes(x=Nombre.comunio, y=Puntos_totales)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + coord_flip() + facet_grid(.~Club)
```

He intentado eso pero no funciona. Es cierto que igual al poner el nombre en el eje de las X (en este caso iría al de las y) quedaría todo muy cargado, pero no sé si es posible poner el nombre de cada jugador top 5 de cada equipo en una subgráfica diferente.

Answer (score 1):

Si entendí bien lo que quieres es generar distintas gráficas por cada club de tu lista, para eso se me hace que lo más práctico sería crear primero una función que genera la gráfica para un solo club y luego aplicarla a los distintos clubs del data frame con la familia de funciones de apply, como se muestra en el código siguiente:

```
Genera_graficas <- function(x){
 Jugadores_final %>% 
 filter(Club == x) %>%
 top_n(5, Puntos_totales) %>% 
 ggplot(aes(x=Nombre.comunio, y=Puntos_totales)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
 coord_flip() + facet_grid(.~Club)
}
lapply(unique(Jugadores_final$Club), Genera_graficas)
```

De esta manera estamos generando tantas gráficas como clubes tenga la base con el top 5 de jugadores por club

Comment: Sí, esa es una opción, pero lo que buscaba era crear 20 subgráficas para poder "compararlas".